# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException in Windows Application

Tags: c#, forms, exception

I have developed a Windows application in Visual Studio 2012 with target framework as .NET 4. I deploy it in a Windows XP SP2 machine. It used to work fine, but now Windows XP was re-installed and the application is not working. I have installed the .NET 4 framework in XP but it shows the following error (from Event Viewer):

```
Application: SGate.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
Stack:
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(System.RuntimeType, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean ByRef, System.RuntimeMethodHandleInternal ByRef, Boolean ByRef)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean, Boolean, Boolean)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(System.Type, Boolean)
   at SGate.Gate..ctor()
   at SGate.Program.Main()
```

I googled for solutions, I figured the exception means "The exception that is thrown when an unrecognized HRESULT is returned from a COM method call." But that doesn't help. Does anyone  know what causes this error?

Program.Main():

```
static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Gate());
        }
    }
```

Gate ctr() and related function:

```
public Gate()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ClearForm();           
        }

private void ClearForm()
        {
            try
            {
                leaveApply = new EmployeeLeaveApplyBO();
                CurrentPageIndex = 1;
                dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
                lblFromDate.Text = "";
                lblLeaveReason.Text = "";
                lblLeavType.Text = "";
                lblName.Text = "";
                lblEmpCode.Text = "";
                lblThumbID.Text = "";
                lblToDate.Text = "";
                lblStatus.Text = "STATUS";
                lblStatus.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                groupBox3.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(224)))), ((int)(((byte)(224)))), ((int)(((byte)(224)))));
                groupBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(224)))), ((int)(((byte)(224)))), ((int)(((byte)(224)))));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                LogUtil.LogError(e.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you have any code?

Comment: Added some code where the error seems to occur.

Comment: Try removing controls from that form until you find out which one is the trouble maker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to debug what is causing this error.
Try breaking when the exception is thrown.

STEPS :- 
 Go to Debug > Exceptions... and use the Find... option to locate System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException. Tick the option to break when it's thrown and then debug your application.

You should be able to find what is the problem.

You can try these if you are not sure exactly what is causing

```
1.Try running visual studio or application as "Run as administrator".
2.Check which platform did you set during build ("AnyCPU, x86, x64")
```

Hope this helps,

Kind Regards

Raghu.M

Comment: Thanks Raghu but it's working fine in Visual Studio and Windows 7. No exceptions are thrown in debug mode. The problem occurs only when I open the exe in Windows XP.